# Why are GWT SimplePager next/last buttons disabled only if range is limited or if the row count isn't exact?

Tags: gwt

Using GWT 2.5.1, SimplePager.java has this method:

```
@Override
protected void onRangeOrRowCountChanged() {

   HasRows display = getDisplay();
   label.setText(createText());

   // Update the prev and first buttons.
   setPrevPageButtonsDisabled(!hasPreviousPage());

   // Update the next and last buttons.
   if (isRangeLimited() || !display.isRowCountExact()) {
      setNextPageButtonsDisabled(!hasNextPage());
      setFastForwardDisabled(!hasNextPages(getFastForwardPages()));
   }
}
```

Why are the next/last buttons enabled/disabled only if range is limited or if the row count isn't exact? I have a pager set to range limited false, and my async data provider specifies that the row count is exact when I update the row count. With this setup, the next/last paging buttons will NEVER be updated!

Am I just using this wrong, or is it a bug?

I worked around the issue by subclassing SimplePager to allow me into that block at the bottom of onRangeOrRowCountChanged():

```
    @Override
    protected void onRangeOrRowCountChanged() {
        boolean rangeLimited = isRangeLimited();
        super.setRangeLimited(true);
        super.onRangeOrRowCountChanged();
        super.setRangeLimited(rangeLimited);
    }
```

Comment: A comment about why this was downvoted would be appreciated. I thought it was a valid and clearly asked question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AIUI, if the range is not limited, you explicitly allow the pager to go beyond the available data and show empty pages.

If the row count is not exact, the next button should be enabled, because `hasNextPage` will return `true` (the fast-forward will be disabled though if it goes beyond the known –though inexact– number of rows). This applies whether the range is limited or not, which may or may not be a bug.

Comment: My intent is that range is limited (I do not want to allow the pager to show empty pages) and row count is exact (I do indeed know the exact number). So you think this is normal usage? Is your answer "this may be a bug?"

Comment: If your intent is that the range is limited, then why are you configuring your pager with `false`?

Comment: I'm not the only person who things SimplePager is odd.  See  https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/google-web-toolkit/last$20page$20too$20big/google-web-toolkit/RedwgreWKB0/_3Q66CkXENUJ  ...  "I noticed that if you call setRangeLimited(false), you get the behavior that you expect, but the forward buttons do not get grayed out."

Comment: Oh, I'm not saying SimplePager is free of bugs, just that the bug isn't in the code you show above. Patches are very welcome though ;-) http://www.gwtproject.org/makinggwtbetter.html

Comment: [EDIT, could not edit comment, reposting edited comment here for clarity]  I said in the other comment that I do not want to allow the pager to show empty pages, but in my original code I set range limited to false because of some odd behavior: For my manual test with 13 items, if range limited is true then when I click next repeatedly, it just jumps back and forth between the first two pages (1-5 and 6-10). Setting range limited to false allows it to continue to the final page (items 11-13). Maybe I'm "doing it wrong?"

Comment: It should show items 9-13 (just tried on the [Showcase](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTable). There's been bug reports about that behavior. Now maybe there are *other* bugs in `SimplePager` (already reported or not), I don't know.

Comment: Well to wrap it up, you did answer the original question. In particular the next/last buttons can't be disabled when range limited is false because in that case the pager has to assume there could be more data. Everything beyond that I guess is just potential issues with the SimplePager. Thanks!